# Printing one list side by side repeatedly

Tags: python

I'd like to print a list side by side repeatedly. What basically happens in my program is I take a row of data from a spreadsheet in the *for* loop and populate the list client = []. I then have a series of *if* and *else* statements to determine whether or not to print a value. I then clear client = [] at the end of each row. This prints top to bottom, but because I want to print the output, I'd like to print the results from each row of data side by side.

Note that each row of my spreadsheet contains data relevant to one client and I essentially want to print a list for each client side by side.

```
client = []

for rowOfCellObjects in Millar_sheet['A2':'AA13']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            client.append(cellObj.value)
            print(client[0]) #policy number
            print(client[9]) #license plate
    if client[12] != "Not Applicable":
        float(client[12])
        print('S.I. = ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % client[12]))
    else:
        print('S.I. ' + client[12])
        print('Basic = ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % client[13]))


client = []
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
PP00041503
PCR 2703 
S.I. Not Applicable
Basic = $1000.00
Loading = 15.0%
Subtotal = $1150.00
SP = 10.0%, -$103.50
$1035.00
NCD = 20.0%, -$207.00
$828.00
Pre-tax Premium is $828.00
Premium Tax = +$49.68
$877.68
RS = +$100
Total = $977.68
--- END OF ROW ---
PP00041503
PCR 2703 
Basic = $1000.00
Loading = 15.0%
Subtotal = $1150.00
SP = 10.0%, -$103.50
$1035.00
NCD = 20.0%, -$207.00
$828.00
Pre-tax Premium is $828.00
Premium Tax = +$49.68
$877.68
RS = +$100
Total = $977.68
--- END OF ROW ---
```

I want it to look like this:

```
PP00041503                          PP00041503
PCR 2703                            PCR 2703 
S.I. Not Applicable                 Basic = $1000.00
Basic = $1000.00                    Loading = 15.0%
Loading = 15.0%                     Subtotal = $1150.00
Subtotal = $1150.00                 SP = 10.0%, -$103.50
SP = 10.0%, -$103.50                $1035.00
$1035.00                            NCD = 20.0%, -$207.00
NCD = 20.0%, -$207.00               $828.00
$828.00                             Pre-tax Premium is $828.00
Pre-tax Premium is $828.00          Premium Tax = +$49.68 
Premium Tax = +$49.68               $877.68
$877.68                             RS = +$100
RS = +$100                          Total = $977.68
Total = $977.68                     --- END OF ROW ---
--- END OF ROW ---
```

Comment: Please add a small example of the current & desired result

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
print('a', end=' ')
print('b', end=' ')
print('c', end=' ')
print('d')
print('e', end='.')

OUTPUT: a b c d
OUTPUT: e.
```

If you don't specify an argument for **end** a new line character will be added after every string you print. You can of course use other characters than space.

If this wasn't what you wanted it might be a good idea to give us an example of your wanted output.

---

**EDIT**

This is a bit messy but it should work. Basically, have a list (*print_list*) that appends a list (*output*) of the output of each row. *print_list* will now be a 2-dimensional list. Loop through the y values and the x values and print the elements. Added the try-except-clause if each row had a different amount of elements to print out.

```
client = []
print_list = []

for rowOfCellObjects in Millar_sheet['A2':'AA13']:
    output = []
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            client.append(cellObj.value)
            output.append(client[0]) #policy number
            output.append(client[9]) #license plate
    if client[12] != "Not Applicable":
        float(client[12])
        output.append('S.I. = ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % client[12]))
    else:
        output.append('S.I. ' + client[12])
        output.append('Basic = ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % client[13]))
    print_list.append(output)


for x in range(len(max(print_list, key=len))):
    for y in range(len(print_list)):
        try:
            print(print_list[y][x], end=" ")
        except IndexError:
            pass
    print("")
```

Comment: Output added to question. I actually need 3 lists side by side.

Comment: Thanks Ted, unfortunately I'm getting an index error.

output.append(client[9]) #license plate
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Jim The only reason for such an error is that the client list doesn't have index 9. In other words, there are less than or equal to 9 elements in your list client. When looking closer at your code, did it really work before? You're creating an empty list *client*, append an element to it and then check for the tenth element right away.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ted. It's not doing what I want it to, so instead I think I will use the python-docx module, create a table and populate what I want in the table in a word file.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the output into a string and print resultant string at the end.

Sample code based on your post description:

```
output_str = '{} {}'.format(client[0], client[9])

if client[12] != "Not Applicable":
    output_str = output_str + ' S.I. = ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % client[12])
else:
    output_str = output_str + ' S.I. ' + client[12]
    output_str = output_str + ' Basic = ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % client[13])
print (output_str)
```

Comment: This would work except I need to print 3 lists side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but you can print side by side as follows:

```
print "one", "two"
print "one",
print "two"
```

You can also save your data in a pandas dataframe (df) and use:

```
print df
```